# precision of double in R

Tags: r

I have to calculate the difference between two long variables in R.
Initially, it was stored as text. But when I tried to convert them into numeric or double to calculate the difference, R fails to recognize that the difference is `1`.

```
testVariable1 = as.numeric("233203300000000001")
testVariable2 = as.numeric("233203300000000002")
testVariable2 - testVariable1
```

Result:

> [1] 0

What can I do to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: see `?.Machine`.   This is an intrinsic limitation of fixed-precision (double in this case) floating point arithmetic.  You need to tell us *what problem you're trying to solve* (not just "I want to compare these numbers", but some more about the context).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(gmp)

as.bigz("233203300000000002")-as.bigz("233203300000000001")


Big Integer ('bigz') :
[1] 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the `bit64` package:

```
library(bit64)
##
testVariable1 <- as.integer64("233203300000000001")
testVariable2 <- as.integer64("233203300000000002")
##
R> testVariable2 - testVariable1
#integer64
#[1] 1
R> as.numeric(testVariable2 - testVariable1)
#[1] 1
```